# Проблема с редактором Delphi

Tags: delphi

Скачал Delphi 7. Запускаю, там открывается окно для редактирования Unit1.pas. Дальше нажимаю File-> New-> Application. Вылетает то же самое. Если хотите, посмотрите скриншот этого окна:

[image]

Comment: Бросьте на форму кнопку, ткните мышью дважды, он сам бросит курсор в нужную часть редактора: там и пишите обработку нажатия на кнопку.

Comment: Ну, и напишите этот код: ShowMessage('Была нажата OK');

Comment: и в чём проблема? ))) 

Comment: @DelphiM0ZG осмеюсь поправить вас, но более приемлемым к ситуации будет код: `ShowMessage('Hello World');`

Comment: Люди, начинайте что-либо изучать с чтения ИНСТРУКЦИЙ, книг для начинающих. Или если с чтением трудно, то можно и Видеокурс посмотреть. А лучше всего (качественнее) пойти учиться!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так и должно быть, там же есть дизайнер формы. Это модуль главной формы, в нём и пишите код Вашей программы (обработчики различных событий от элементов управления). А если хочется исходник посмотреть, то так: **Project -> ViewSource**.

Comment: В какой именно части надо писать код программы? private, public или
implementation

Comment: Вообще-то в модулях раздел реализации - Implementation - здесь нужно описывать процедуры и функции, а их названия - в зависимости от уровня видимости: Private - только в этом модуле можно будет пользоваться, Public - пользоваться процедурой можно везде (из этой программы).

Comment: А, вообще, как я понял, Вам нужно: <a href="http://masterlite.delphicomponent.ru/">сюда</a>. Там видеокурс для "чайников".

Comment: В общем как в Pascal. А как например вывести какой-нибудь текст  в это окно? К примеру как мне выполнить вот этот код: 
var
  buttonSelected : Integer;
 begin
  // Отображение диалога с подтверждением
  buttonSelected := MessageDlg('Confirmation',mtError, mbOKCancel, 0);

  // Показ типа выбранной кнопки
  if buttonSelected = mrOK     then ShowMessage('Была нажата OK');
  if buttonSelected = mrCancel then ShowMessage('Была нажата Cancel');
 end;